# Ionic 2 publish event not working for second time

Tags: ionic-framework, publish-subscribe, ionic-events

```
in app.component.ts  
this.events.subscribe('user:created', (val) => {
    console.log('hello called');
}

and called it from home.ts
this.events.publish('user:created','userDataHome');
```

it works when app load first time but when i logout & login again the subscribe method not getting called

Comment: Can you show more code for the login and log out functionality

Comment: does your data change in the home.ts? if not, the subscribe won't be called again because no data has been changed. to test it do a setTimeout(() => this.events.publish('user:created','test2'), 500);